# Mangled cyrillic character encoding

Tags: ms-access, encoding, character-encoding, cyrillic

I have an Access database that has text written using Latin and Cyrillic alphabets. Latin letters are all good, but Cyrillic letters were not encoded correctly. I managed to figure what some of the letters were substituted with. I'm not sure if the correct letter should be upper or lowercase. Any idea what went wrong here?

```
+--------------+------------------+
| Bad Encoding | Correct Encoding |
+--------------+------------------+
| в            | г                |
| Г            | а                |
| Д            | о                |
| Ё            | э                |
| Й            | р                |
| ї            | с                |
| М            | х                |
| м            | е                |
| о            | м                |
| ь            | б                |
| щ            | и                |
+--------------+------------------+
```

Comment: By what mechanism(s) were the Cyrillic characters inserted into the database?

Comment: @GordThompson I'm not sure as I did not create the database.

Comment: What is the encoding used with the database? cp1252, cp1251, ...? How did you figure out those correspondences? Why not sure about upper/lower case? What sort of data do you have in the text columns? names, addresses, part numbers, part descriptions? Checked for Russian surnames ending with ova (F) and ov (M) ? Or is the underlying language Ukrainian, Belarusian, Serbian, ...?

Comment: @JohnMachin I'm not sure what encoding was used. I looked all over the table settings and I don't see it anywhere. I'm not sure about the lower/upper case simply because I don't know what it was originally. Looking at the data I would say with 90% certainty that only one case is used and if I had to guess it is most likely uppercase. The database is of the Russian plate numbers which is how I managed to determine some of the letters